# Active Directory: Add New User C# / VB

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, user-permissions

I browsed other questions and couldn't find the answer.

What is the appropriate way to add a new user to a active directory specific group when the "current user" running the application does not have access rights to add new users?

I am currently authenticating as the domain Administrator to do it, but obviously that is a security no-no and I don't want the Administrator user's credentials hard-codeded in my code.

I assume the answers is not in my code itself but that I have to create a user in the Active Directory that has privileges to add users.

So my question is a combination of a AD and a Coding question:

1) How do I create a AD user that ONLY has access rights to add users to specific  OU and CN security group?

2) Is their any way possible to not hard-code the password for this user?

Or... am I going about this entirely wrong?

Here is my current VB.NET code:

```
 Public Function CreateUser(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String, ByVal DisplayName As String) As Boolean
    Try

        'Dim catalog As Catalog = New Catalog()
        Dim de As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry()

        de.Path = "LDAP://OU=TS2xUsers,DC=dc,DC=example,DC=com"
        de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure
        de.Username = "Administrator"
        de.Password = "foopassword"

        '1. Create user accountd
        Dim users As DirectoryEntries = de.Children
        Dim newuser As DirectoryEntry = users.Add("CN=" & DisplayName, "user")
        newuser.Properties("givenname").Value = DisplayName
        newuser.Properties("name").Value = DisplayName
        newuser.Properties("displayName").Value = DisplayName
        newuser.Properties("SAMAccountName").Value = UserName
        newuser.Properties("userPrincipalName").Value = UserName & "@dc.example.com"
        'newuser.Properties("OU").Value = "TS2xUsers"

        newuser.CommitChanges()


        Dim ret As Object = newuser.Invoke("SetPassword", Password)
        newuser.CommitChanges()

        Dim exp As Integer = CInt(newuser.Properties("userAccountControl").Value)
        exp = exp And Not &H2 'enable acccount
        exp = exp Or &H10000 'dont expire password
        newuser.Properties("userAccountControl").Value = exp
        newuser.CommitChanges()
        ''' 5. Add user account to groups
        If MakeTSUser(newuser) = False Then
            Return False
            newuser.Close()
            de.Close()
        End If

        newuser.Close()
        de.Close()
        Return True


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed to create user due to the following reason: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Return False
    End Try

End Function

Private Function MakeTSUser(ByVal deUser As DirectoryEntry) As Boolean
    Try


        Dim deRBGroup As New DirectoryEntry
        deRBGroup.Path = "LDAP://CN=TSUsers,CN=Builtin,DC=dc,DC=example,DC=com"
        deRBGroup.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure
        deRBGroup.Username = "Administrator"
        deRBGroup.Password = "foopassword"

        Dim deDomainUsers As New DirectoryEntry
        deDomainUsers.Path = "LDAP://CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=dc,DC=example,DC=com"
        deDomainUsers.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure
        deDomainUsers.Username = "Administrator"
        deDomainUsers.Password = "foopassword"

        Dim primaryGroupToken As Object = Nothing

        deRBGroup.Invoke("Add", New Object() {deUser.Path.ToString()})
        deRBGroup.CommitChanges()

        'Get Primary Group Token of MYGROUP

        deRBGroup.Invoke("GetInfoEx", New Object() {New Object() {"primaryGroupToken"}, 0})

        primaryGroupToken = deRBGroup.Properties("primaryGroupToken").Value


        'Assign Primary Group Token value of MYROUP to the User's PrimaryGroupID

        deUser.Properties("primaryGroupID").Value = primaryGroupToken

        deUser.CommitChanges()


        'Remove the User from "Domain Users" group
        deDomainUsers.Invoke("Remove", New Object() {deUser.Path.ToString()})
        deDomainUsers.CommitChanges()

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try


End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the appropriate way to add a new user to a active directory specific group when the "current user" running the application does not have access rights to add new users?

Run the app as a user that does have those permissions... but you already know this:

> I assume the answers is ... to create a user in the Active Directory that has privileges to add users.
>
> Is their any way possible to not hard-code the password for this user?

Good question. One way to do this by setting up a Windows Scheduled Task. You can setup a task to run on demand, with no actual schedule, and to run as any user you want, including your new service account. You will have to put in the password for that user when you setup the task, but only when you first setup the task, and the actual password won't be stored... only the authentication token, which is not transferable. Then your desktop application can trigger the task to start.

Another way to do this is to grant the unprivileged HR or helpdesk users who run your app permissions to [create new users just within your specific OU](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/72de8466-4424-4f16-9d1e-c1f9f72eab6d/delegated-ou-to-just-create-users?forum=winserverDS). In the case of a web app, you can also do this for the user account that runs the web site, as long as you have appropriate logging and auditing in place.

The other option is to create a separate service to create the users, which runs as the appropriate user. This could be a web service, where less-privileged authenticated users can post the new account information, or it could be a Windows service doing something like watching a file share, where your unprivileged users then have the ability or write to the file share. Then your program can know how to call the service or write the correct file formats into the share.

Comment: I suppose I can give the current user access to add users, but I only want them to have access to create a new user in the same OU and CN.  How would I go about setting up a the current AD user group to give access rights to add users with the  same equal rights?

Comment: The link in the answer explains how to limit the privilege to a specific OU.